# How to align column in GridLayout RecycleView using setSpanSizeLookup in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

Hello Guys I have problem for add Gridlayout using RecycleView, but I can not leave aligned the line with to Column.

Could you please help me to understand how to do for align the line with 2 column follow my code.

[Printout of the my Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnaGf.png)

---

Tab1.class

```
      private List<Consultorio> consultorioList;
private ClinicaAdapter adapter;
protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.itens_fragment);
    GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(v.getContext(), 3);
    manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return (3 - position % 3);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);



    /*LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);*/
    List<Consultorio> list = new ArrayList<Consultorio>();
    Consultorio c0 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Consultorio c1 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Consultorio c2 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Consultorio c3 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Consultorio c4 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Consultorio c5 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Consultorio c6 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Consultorio c7 = new Consultorio(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    list.add(c0);
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c2);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c4);
    list.add(c5);
    list.add(c6);
    list.add(c7);

    adapter = new ClinicaAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
```

}

ClinicaAdapter.class

```
 public class ClinicaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClinicaAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
List<Consultorio> consultorioList;
Boolean isHomeList = false;

private List<Consultorio> mEspecialistas;

public ClinicaAdapter(List<Consultorio> data) {
    mEspecialistas = data;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.clinica_medica_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Consultorio consultorio = consultorioList.get(position);

    holder.imageViewPhoto.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mEspecialistas.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imageViewPhoto;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinc_img);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is Answer for my question.

In Tab1.class I put the follow code:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.itens_fragment);

    GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(v.getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return (position % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

ref: http://pt.slideshare.net/devunwired/mastering-recyclerview-layouts